# Написание причастий с раздельным "не"

Tags: participle

В этот раз озадачена душа моя следующей ситуацией:

*Я видел (не)спасшегося в тот день человека*

Я не понимаю адекватный и разумный повод писать причастие раздельно от частицы **"не"**.

Как-то давно ко мне пришло логическое понимание, почему **"не"** должно отделяться от прилагательных в оборотах противопоставления, например:

*Это была не большая машина, а маленькая*

Я объяснил это самому себе так, что **"не"** и **"а"** - как две чаши весов, на которых сравниваются определённые вещи. Таким образом мы не можем написать

*Это была небольшая машина, а маленькая*

Ибо получится, что одной чаши не станет, а тогда весы работать перестанут, так как картина будет следующая:

*Это была крохотная машина, а маленькая*

Ведь мы же можем заменить **"небольшая"** на **"крохотная"**, к примеру, почему нет. В таком случае противопоставление лишается одной из половин, и всё становится очень печально.

Таким образом я понял это правило умом и разумом, а не зубрёжкой. Понять, почему нельзя писать слитно **"не"** с причастиями я умом понять не могу.

Возьмём, например, это же **"неспасшийся"**. Мы же можем сказать

*Неспасшийся человек был очень добр при жизни*

Зависимых слов нет, пишем слитно. Можно перефразировать

*Погибший человек был очень добр при жизни*

Всё отлично. Дак почему мы не можем сказать

*Я видел неспасшегося в тот день человека*

если мы можем представить **"неспасшегося"** как **"погибшего"** по примеру **"небольшой"** = **"крохотный"**, получив

*Я видел погибшего в тот день человека*

На данный момент эдакое правило мне видится буквально **"выщебетанным"** устами какого-то очередного дяденьки, который взял и расписал очередной учебник, после чего, непонятно почему, его постулаты стали считаться эталоном русского языка. Есть какое-то логическое понимание верности этого правила? Просто хотелось бы действительно **ПОНЯТЬ** логику правила, а не тупо **ЗАЗУБРИТЬ**.

Answer (score 2):

При отсутствии подчиненных слов «не» принадлежит причастию и потому является приставкой.

При наличии же подчиненных слов «не» относится не к одному слову, а к обороту в целом, становясь союзом: `человека какого? не <спасшегося в тот день>`. Сравните с полноценным противопоставлением, где мы тоже сравниваем конструкции в целом: `человека какого? не <спасшегося в тот день>, а <погибшего при таких-то обстоятельствах>`.

Почему причастие при отрицании подтягивает всю зависящую от него цепочку слов — не знаю. Возможно, семантическая особенность, появившаяся при отделении русского (или вообще славянских — тут надо сравнивать) языков от более общего предка.

Comment: Тогда такой вопрос - как определить, что является зависимым словом, а что - нет? **Не спасшийся ВЧЕРА человек** - зависимое, **не спасшийся ТАМ человек** - зависимое, **не спасшийся ДОЛЖНЫМ ОБРАЗОМ человек** - зависимое, **Не спасшийся ЗНАКОМЫЙ НАМ человек** - независимое. Можно ли, я уже философствую, назвать зависимым всё, к чему можно задать вопрос от самого причастия, а не от существительного? **Не спасшийся (когда?) вчера**, **не спасшийся (где?) там**,  *неспасшийся (как?) должным образом**, но **неспасшийся знакомый нам (кто?) человек (какой?) - связь уже от существительного.

Comment: Любые зависимые слова, отнесенные к причастию, можно считать обстоятельствами действия, а если таковые появляются,  то причастие начинает проявлять себя как глагольная, а не признаковая  форма.  Соответственно,  частица НЕ отрицает действие в глагольной форме, поэтому пишется раздельно.  Так что ВСЁ ПРЕДЕЛЬНО ПРОСТО.

Comment: И еще: надо различать однородные и неоднородные отношения для определений.  Неспасшийся (= погибший)  знакомый нам человек?  Конечно, всё это не из реальной речи,  ну да ладно. ЗАПЯТУЮ здесь надо ставить, обозначая однородные определения. Зависимое слово относится к прилагательному, а не к причастию. А у вас получается «микс» из двух определений и одного зависимого слова. Тоже новая архитектурная форма?

Answer (score 1):

1. **The participle as a verb form**

The participle is not an independent part of speech, but a special verb form, although it has the grammatical form of an adjective. The participle denotes a mark **as an action** related **to time**, while the adjective denotes a mark as a **permanent quality.** (I even believe that we can say otherwise: the participle denotes an action as a mark, but this is only a private opinion.)

The participle has the values of time and voice, and these are grammatical marks of the verb: «неспасшийся» is the valid past participle.

**2. Prefix "НЕ" and negative particle "НЕ"**

The adjective denotes a qualitative mark. The prefix «НЕ» is not connected to every adjective. For example, there is no word "некрасный", since it is only a negation, we should write «не красный». Adjectives with a prefix «НЕ»  denote the opposite sign (for example, near is almost close).
Negative particle «НЕ» is written separately with verbs, since it denies the action.

**3. Influence of dependent words**

Dependent words do not affect the spelling of negative particle «НЕ» with adjectives, for example: неглубокая река – неглубокая в этом месте река.
Single participles converge with adjectives, denoting a mark as a permanent quality, but **when dependent words appear, the constant quality begins to manifest itself as an ACTION:**

незамерзшее озеро (на нем нет льда) – еще не замершее озеро (озеро еще не замерзло);

неспасшийся  (погибший) человек – не спасшийся в тот день человек (человек не спасся в тот день).

Let's pay attention to the fact that dependent words **pass from the verb to the participial turn.**

4. This rule has often been suggested to simplify, but it is very closely related **to grammar**, however, as well as all rules in Russian spelling. Grammar is a serious science, you should not touch it.

Comment: +1. Perhaps what you call “a sign” is better should be called “a mark”.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше замечание и извините мой плохой английский, я просто хотела на этом форуме научиться писать на грамматические темы, используя соответствующие термины. И со словом "sign" у меня это плохо получалось, так что я перебрала несколько вариантов.